# Firebase - Check if data exist and add them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if user is the member of a specific team, if user isn't he will then be ask to join, if he is, then he will be directed to a page. I did find some of the similar question but for somehow I still couldn't add user to the database. Below is my code and this code crash whenever i click on one of the list.

```
databaseMembers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("members");

listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the selected team
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            checkMember();


            //creating an intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);

            //putting team name and id to intent
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());

            //starting the activity with intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

private void checkMember(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String teamMember = user.getEmail();
    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(teamMember)){
                finish();
            }
            else{
                databaseMembers.push().setValue(teamMember);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-07 12:44:41.167 19091-19091/com.example.user.stfv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.user.stfv2, PID: 19091
                                                                    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: haha@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzjl(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.hasChild(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.example.user.stfv2.MainActivity$8.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:352)
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My Database:

[image]

When user click on "heng" team, it will check if user's email exist in the database, if isn't it will then add user's email as a teamMember. I can add the user who created the team, but I can't seem to add users who wants to join later. Really appreciate if someone could help me. Let me know if there's lack of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Firebase does not accept `.` (dot) symbol in the key. So in order to use an email address, you need to have an encoding method. The email addres must be `name@mail,com` (see the `,` comma) in stead of nume@email.com as it is in your case. These are the methods to encode and decode the email address.

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

This methods will solve your problem.

Comment: Where should I put these methods? Anywhere in the code? Sorry I don't know how to use encode/decode method.

Comment: Do you mind explain to me how I should use these codes?

Comment: In your activity in which you need them or in a helper class.

Comment: still the same, i put your code right after my checkMember function

Comment: If you get the same error, it means that you insert the email address uncoded, containing `.` which is not permited. So in order to add the email in the correct format, you need to do something like this: `String encodedEmailAddress = encodeUserEmail(userEmail);` In which `userEmail` is the email that you are using now and `encodedEmailAddress` is the email which you need to insert in the database.

Comment: Thx man added successful :) Do you mind help me with another small things? The email is added into "members" but I want it to be added into whichever the team name the user clicked, so that the email is store into, let's say "heng" for example.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is clearly mentioned in your logcat:

> Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

I think it doesn't even accept '@'. The proper way to add your user into the DB is to use users uid.

Eg:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

In your code you can do something like this:

```
private void checkMember(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String teamMember = user.getUid();
    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(teamMember)){
                finish();
            }
            else{
                databaseMembers.push().setValue(teamMember);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is written your logcat:

Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

But I also look over your code. You can write firebase Query like this.

```
databaseMembers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("members");
Query q = databaseMembers.orderbyChild("heng").equalTo(user.getEmail());
```

You can write dynamic I just give a example.